# What is the definition of a Jacobi operator for a functional?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations

I read some articles recently where the authors say that the terminology "Jacobi operator" emphasizes "the close relationship between the second variation" of a functional and the linearization of another one (related). They talk about "the Jacobi operator of a functional".

After all, what is the definition of a Jacobi operator in this context of Calculus of Variations? What is its relation with the second variation?

Comment: I wonder if there is a precise definition, but Jacobi operator usually refers to second variation at a critical point. That is, if $g$ is a critical value of a function $\mathscr L$, then $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}|_{t=0} \mathscr L(f_t) = \int L f \cdot f$ (where $f =f'_t$) and $L$ is the Jacobi operator.

Comment: That makes sense. I asked because it bothers me the fact that I couldn't find a precise definition. So, there may not exist one! Thanks for your comment.